# How to make Google crawl my Ajax content (external XML)?

Tags: xml, ajax, external, web-crawler

(To begin with, sorry for my English, it's not my first language)

I have a one-page website where I got a portfolio showing our works. The list of projects are loaded from an external xml file with ajax on page load. When I click on a project, an overlay comes to view with the project images and description. That description is loaded on click on a project with ajax again. The problem is: my projects' descriptions are NOT on my page on load, so Google doesn't see my content. The descriptions would be quite useful in google search result to help me get more views...

I tried to put the link to my xml file in my sitemap.xml but google doesn't read it.

I can't include all the content directly in my html page because having an external xml file is really easier to add project if there is no IT employee at the moment.

I made a research on that subject but only got vague answers... I saw that google now reads external xlm content loaded with ActionScript when you have a Flash file, but is it doing the same in html with javascript?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For google to index the various ajax states of your page, you have to adhere to their Ajax Crawling Scheme (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)...

Basically you need to ensure that each state of your page can be loaded via url (not just a button click), i.e. if button 1 links to an about us page, then you also have to ensure that the about us state can be loaded via a url hash `/#!about-us`....

The next step is to intercept a request made by the web bot (explained on the link above), and scrape your site server side using a headless browser (i.e. QT + capybara-webkit, HtmlUnit, etc.) at the state indicated in the url, then deliver the generated dom back to the requesting bot.

If you are using ruby, theres a gem to handle this page interception and rendering of DOM snapshots at rubygems; `gem install google_ajax_crawler`, source code at https://github.com/benkitzelman/google-ajax-crawler.... you'll have to implement the client side routing yourself first tho.... shouldn't be too hard to do - somewhere in the page js do something like

`if(document.location.hash == '#!about-us') { $('.about-btn').click(); }`